# how to i create new exiftool tag for pdf files as using exiftool config file on gnu/linux?

Tags: exif

There is no subtitle meta tag for pdf in exiftool. Therefore I want to add new exif tag for pdf files, it's name must be PdfSubTitle. To do this, exiftool has a [guide page](https://www.exiftool.org/config.html). But I don't understand because my knowledge of perl and exif not enough. Also there is no example for pdf files in the guide. How can I do that?

When everything goes right it should be like:

```
$ exiftool -config exif.config -PdfSubTitle="Sub Title" file.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define your `XMP` tag (a complete [example](https://exiftool.org/config.html) here)

```
$ cat config.cfg
          
%Image::ExifTool::UserDefined = (
  'Image::ExifTool::XMP::pdfx' => {
     PdfSubTitle => {
         Writable => 'string',
     },
  },
);   
1; # end
```

Then with following command the tag and it's value will be added:

```
exiftool -config config.cfg -PdfSubTitle="Sub Title" test.pdf
```

Confirm:

```
$ exiftool -PdfSubTitle test.pdf
  Pdf Sub Title                   : Sub Title
 
$ exiftool test.pdf | grep 'Pdf Sub Title'
  Pdf Sub Title                   : Sub Title
```

Comment: Thanks! This is so helpful for me.